# Maximize form using send/postmessage User32.dll

Tags: c#, sendmessage, postmessage

I have windows application, i need to maximize the window/form.

I tried

```
    public const int WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN = 0xA1;
    public const int HT_CAPTION = 0x2;
    SendMessage(Handle, WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN, HT_CAPTION, 0);

and 

    int WM_SIZE = 0x0005;
    int SIZE_MAXIMIZED = 2;
    SendMessage(Main, WM_SIZE, SIZE_MAXIMIZED, 0);
```

Nothing is not working.

Can any show me what the right wat to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As described in the documentation, `WM_SIZE` is a notification, sent to the window in the event of the window's size changing. Sending it to a window won't change the size of the window. Your sending `WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN` appears to be an attempt to fake a click in the caption bar. That won't work, at least not the way you've done it.

Use [`ShowWindowAsync`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ms633549.aspx) passing the handle of the window that you wish to maximize, and `SW_MAXIMIZE`.

Comment: hhmmm.....i did this                                    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern bool ShowWindowAsync(int hWnd, int SW_MAXIMIZE);
                        ShowWindowAsync(Main, 2);  and it didn't work

Comment: Perhaps the window handle is wrong, and why did you choose to pass 2? What do you think 2 means? It doesn't mean maximize. The documentation that I linked to is reasonably clear I think. Also, "didn't work" is never any use. Nobody but you has any idea what that means.

Comment: Find it  "Hide"              {$=  0}
        "Normal"             {$=  1}
        "ShowMinimized"      {$=  2}
        "Maximize"           {$=  3}
        "ShowNoActivate"     {$=  4}
        "Show"               {$=  5}
        "Minimize"           {$WinStateInt =  6}
        "ShowMinNoActive"    {$WinStateInt =  7}
        "ShowNA"             {$WinStateInt =  8}
        "Restore"            {9}
        "ShowDefault"        {10}
        "ForceMinimize"      {11}
        default    {$=  1}

Comment: [DllImport("user32")]
    public static extern int ShowWindowAsync(int hwnd, int nCmdShow); and ShowWindowAsync(Main, 3) Thanx man

Comment: Use `IntPtr` for a window handle, it's a pointer sized thing. Use the declarations here (http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.showwindowasync) and here (http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/Enums/ShowWindowCommand.html)

Answer (score 1):

Maximize is a SYSCOMMAND, Try this instead:

```
        int WM_SYSCOMMAND = 0x112;
        int SC_MAXIMIZE = 0xf030;
        SendMessage(handle, WM_SYSCOMMAND, SC_MAXIMIZE, IntPtr.Zero);
```